# Java recursion questio

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a method that will print a pyramid with a height based on a height parameter with recursion.

A sample output would be:
printPyramid(5);

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

It sends me a stack overflow error when it needs to start decrementing the number of stars back down to 1 and I can't figure out where my logic is off. It successfully increments upwards, checks if the iteration is larger than the height, and then would begin decrementing, and stops the recursion when the iteration hits zero --- but I'm still getting errors.

```
    public static void printPyramid(int height){
        if(height == 0) {
            return;
        } else {        
            printPyramidRow(1, height);
        }
    }
    
    public static void printPyramidRow(int it, int height) {
        if(it <= 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            printRow(it);
            if (it < height) {
                printPyramidRow(it + 1, height);
            } else {
                printPyramidRow(it - 1, height);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void printRow(int numOfStars) {
        for(int i = 1; i < numOfStars + 1; i++) {
            if(i == numOfStars) {
                System.out.println("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger? What did you find?

Comment: Supposing height is 4, the number of asterisks goes 1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4 .... And back and forth forever. You need some check which will let you know whether you're ascending or descending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        if (iteration < height) {
            printTriangle(iteration + 1, height);
        } else {
            printTriangle(iteration - 1, height);
        }
```

This section of code is problematic. You initially have `iteration` less than `height` and you increment it. After reaching max, you decrement once but in the next recursion you are incrementing again. You are stuck in the increment and decrement around the max.

You may want to change your if condition.